# I am getting No such property while giving target step in soapui

Tags: soapui

I am taking the value from the one response and coamparing that value with one integer and based on the boolean i am navigating to the other step.

It is showing No such property: testrunner. Please let me know why this is happening..

if (cardScheme == '20172')

testRunner.runTestStepByName( "Submit Order 1" )

else

testRunner.runTestStepByName( "Submit Order" )

Answer (score 2):

Groovy is case-sensitive language. You are using somewhere testrunner instead of testRunner.